# error while connecting to mysql in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an error while connecting my project into mysql database so i have added the code bellow to my button to fetch all rows and display it in a gridView

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;password=;database=y;");
            string strSQL = "select * from welcome";
            myconn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter mydata = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, myconn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydata);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            mydata.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            myconn.Close();
        }
```

When running the the app it shows an error in myconn.Open();

```
An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: The host localhost does not support SSL connections.

and it pointed to myconn.Open();

Comment: no answer i need to solve this error urgently

Comment: You probably have an error either in your connection string or in your select statement. Verify that "welcome" is a table in your mysql database (check for case sensitivity). Also make sure that your database name and password are correct.

Comment: my database username and password is correct

Answer (score 1):

change `myconn` to :

```
MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;password=;database=y;sslmode=none");
```

Make sure that you are adding `sslmode=none` in `myconn`

Answer (score 0):

better try with Entity Frame work

1. Add ADO.NET Entity model,If will ask to connect db and give some name(ex :userentities)
2. Then, use below code in your coding

userentities context = new userentities();

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var dbTransactionContext = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //then do the operation
            }
        }
```

It's really easy

or other wise follow these steps
1. add your connection string in web config

```
 <add name="UserContext" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password='';database=databasename;convert zero datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

2. Add follow codes in your code

   private MySqlConnection con;
   con = new MySqlConnection();
   con.ConnectionString  =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserContext"].ConnectionString;
   con.Open();

Comment: connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;password='';database=y;convert zero datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

Comment: change your connection string as above and give a try

Comment: I Didn't touched my code ,   I just added the above code in my webConfig and click run it shows this error(HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.)

Comment: I modified the code and i got same errors as on my Post

Comment: i got this error {"The host localhost does not support SSL connections."}